# create flag on image like google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am going to put flag on my image like in Google Maps in an Android app.

When the user clicks on a flag, a comment is displayed and when the image is zoomed, the location of flags does not change.

But I don't know how to do it. Can anybody guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use custom ItemizedOverlay for placing the markers and overriding the onTap event in that class to be able to click on them.

http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/android-google-maps-tutorial-part-5-adding-multiple-images-to-google-maps-using-itemizedoverlay/

Following this tutorial would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This library does what you ask for
[mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)